# Meteor.logout() causing memory leak in React

Tags: reactjs, meteor

When I logout of my meteor app I get memory leak error. It seems to happen about 50% of the time and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Can someone please explain what's wrong with my method.

**Error message**

Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

**App details**

Metoer, React, React-Router V4

Path: `LogoutButton.jsx`

```
class LogoutButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logoutRedirect: false
    };

    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
  }

  handleLogout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    Meteor.logout(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      } else {
        this.setState({ logoutRedirect: true });
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const logoutRedirect = this.state;

    if (logoutRedirect.logoutRedirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-link dropdown-item text-dark"
        onClick={this.handleLogout}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOutAlt} className="mr-2 text-dark" />
        Logout
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'll break this down for you in understanding what the error is, why you are running into it and some possible ideas for a solution.

Your component `LogoutButton` is running into a scenario where it is unmounted (it is fully unrendered) but is attempting to trigger a state change within the component. This is generally just bad state flow generally stemming from doing some asynchronous action that takes time to do and then triggering a setState when there's nothing to, well, setState in.

Looking at your code it sounds like what you're trying to do is this:

1. You have a `<LogoutButton />` rendered onto the screen and when a
   user clicks it, they're supposed to be redirected.
2. When a user clicks the button, it triggers `handleLogout` which explicitly calls `Meteor.logout` (I assume this is what is formally logging the user out from the session) and then proceed to call `setState`.

Most likely, `Meteor.logout` has some side-effect here to make it so your `LogoutButton` is no longer mounted or rendered. By the time your component gets to the step where it needs to call `setState`, your component is unmounted (maybe some parent component has decided to not show it anymore, etc).

I don't know enough about React-Router (which is what I assume the `<Redirect />` is from but it looks like `history.push` or passing a prop called `push` to `<Redirect />` is something worth considering. See [this article](https://dev.to/calier/implementing-client-side-logout-with-react-router-v4-3a84).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone can shed more light on this I'd really appreciate it. The problem appears to be coming from how I handle my authenticated routes. I've solved the error with the code below, however, I'm not really sure why this works so I'm not able to give an explanation. The solution was to change the order of operations. First, update state to redirect route and then logout user.

```
class LogoutButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logoutRedirect: false
    };

    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleLogout);
  }

  handleLogout = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ logoutRedirect: true });
    Meteor.logout(err => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const logoutRedirect = this.state;

    if (logoutRedirect.logoutRedirect) {
      return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return (
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-link dropdown-item text-dark"
        onClick={this.handleLogout}
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOutAlt} className="mr-2 text-dark" />
        Logout
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't work. The workaround, as a dirty hack was to force the app to reload once the user had logged out.

Answer (score 0):

---

step1 .meteor 
folder add this package : 
accounts-ui
accounts-google
accounts-password
accounts-base
std:accounts-ui
useraccounts:bootstrap
// 
step 2 : 
folder: imports/startup
create folder name "accounts" add accounts-config.js and paste the code.
change FlowRouter.go('/account/sign-in') to  
step 3 : Add function to your button. paste this   
  `let handleLogout = () => {
    AccountsTemplates.logout()
  }`

```js
const LogoutButton = () => {
   
  let handleLogout = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    AccountsTemplates.logout()
  }

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-link dropdown-item text-dark"
      onClick={handleLogout}
    >
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSignOutAlt} className="mr-2 text-dark" />
      Logout
    </button>
  )
}
```

Note: I'm using account base.

```js
// Configure Accounts Templates default
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  enablePasswordChange: true,
  sendVerificationEmail: true,
  enforceEmailVerification: true,
  showForgotPasswordLink: true,
  negativeValidation: true,
  positiveValidation: true,
  negativeFeedback: true,
  positiveFeedback: true,
  // Proceed to main page as you log out..
  onLogoutHook: () => {
    <Redirect to="/" />
  }
})
```

Comment: It's great you submitted some code but how does this solve the OP's question? What about your code prevents the memory leak? What did they do wrong?

Comment: Currently also using meteor, react.

Comment: Call this anytime you want to logout:   let handleLogout = () => {
    AccountsTemplates.logout()
  }

Comment: Yes, probably your issue solve. meteor package : accounts-ui
accounts-google
accounts-password
accounts-base
session@1.2.0
std:accounts-ui
useraccounts:bootstrap

Comment: I try my best to explain. :D